# Haver+de apenas no presente do indicativo?

Tags: conjugações

No seguimento desta [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3603/hei-de-ver-jo%C3%A3o-amanh%C3%A3-should-there-be-a-hyphen), ficamos a saber que, graças ao AO90, já não precisamos de escrever com hífen o verbo 'Haver'. Gostaria de saber se, imediatamente antes do período abrangido pelo AO90, o verbo 'Haver' se conjugava com '-de' apenas no Presente do Indicativo, ou noutros tempos verbais também.

Comment: há-de ser=Portugal, antes/hé de ser, sempre foi no Brasil. Também se aplica a hão de ser. O plural. Old man in the sea? Hm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O hífen era apenas usado com as formas monossilábicas do verbo *haver*, e apenas  o Presente do Indicativo tem formas monossilábicas. Portanto, em nenhum dos outros tempos se usava (ou usa) o hífen:

> - *par=ext11693-eco-94b-1*: **Havia de ser** em Portugal...
> - *par=ext34012-soc-92a-1*: Por que não **haveriam de fazer** o mesmo contra a polícia ?
> - *par=ext471826-clt-98a-1*: «Meu rapazinho, nós nunca mais nos **haveremos de separar**. "
> - *par=ext676414-clt-95b-2*: Segundo Capela Miguel, presidente do CAR, o convite dos Festivais de Gil Vicente ao TEP é um exemplo da preocupação que **houve de levar** a Guimarães «o bom teatro» para uma iniciativa que pretende «voltar a recriar o ciclo de dinamização cultural nas pequenas comunidades locais», o que também é conseguido com uma série de cinco espectáculos em vários pontos do concelho, a cargo de três grupos amadores: o Teatro de Cerzedo, o Teatro da Hoste D. Nuno e o Teatro da Coelima .
> - *par=ext1178468-clt-soc-95b-2*: «São desses, sim senhor, então eu não **houvera de saber**, anda nisto há muitos anos, são fuseis», repete peremptória .
> - *par=ext488437-soc-95b-2*: Foi em 1395 que o rei D. João I, em alvará régio datado de 23 de Agosto, mandou que, «em caso que se algum fogo se levantasse, o que Deus não queira, que todos os carpinteiros e calafates venham àquele lugar, cada um com o seu machado, para **haverem de atalhar** o dito fogo .
> - *par=ext504455-opi-96a-2*: Ou ninguém que decida em tempo útil aquilo que é sua função decidir, **havendo de munir**-se de grosas de pareceres antes de cometer o atrevimento de um despacho outrora corrente .
> - *par=ext1448113-soc-98a-2*: Porque se a ideia fosse atacar a insulabridade das «ilhas», Almeida Garrett postulava a demolição de 7300 casas («não contando com os prédios do antigo Porto que **hajam de ser apeados** e que vão ruindo todos os anos») .
> - *par=ext95826-soc-98b-3*: «Se no nosso testemunho e na nossa acção de bispos **houvéssemos de pensar** sempre o que pode dividir, nada ou muito pouco de útil poderíamos dizer ou fazer. "
> - *par=ext1448572-nd-91b-3*: Eis a cópia fiel de alguns desses documentos, destinados a servirem de norma aos candidatos que **houverem de mostrar**-se aptos a serem providos nas funções que o orçamento remunera e que o Governo distribui :

Os exemplos são do [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CETEMPUBLICO).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. ;) no 3º exemplo a partir do fim, com a expressão «hajam de ser apeados», qual o significado do verbo 'haver' ? Poderia traduzir por «tenham de ser apeados»?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Não tenho a certeza, mas parece-me que a noção de obrigação está bastante esbatida e que portanto está mais próximo de _que venham a ser apeados_ (que exprime uma eventualidade) ou simplesmente _sejam/forem_ do que de _que tenham de ser apeados_. Um exemplo que creio ser similar, do séc. XIX: _O governo mandará elaborar os regulamentos a que se referem os artigos 177.° e 178.°, a tempo dos [oficiais] que hajam de ser promovidos poderem conhecer com a devida anteced[ê]ncia as provas de aptidão a que tenham de ficar sujeitos._

Comment: Há muitos exemplos parecidos em textos legais até meados do séc XX.